# Direct URL SIP Client for Python3 (Windows and Linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sip

I have a SIP URL. I would like to connect to this SIP URL with python. I would also like to record the session.

OS: Windows 10 (should also work on Linux)

Python Version: Python 3.8.3 64-bit

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems are you running into?

Comment: @Grismar couldn't find one for python3 that supported direct sip url :(

Comment: What do you mean by "direct" SIP URL?

Comment: I have a URL/IP (SIP URL) (not phone number) and I want to connect ip to ip

Comment: The code seems messy, but have you looked at this: http://cs.uccs.edu/~cs526/svoip/src/shtoom/shtoom/sip.py

Comment: just looked at it, i guess it is a start, any other ideas (can be messy, but have to have documentation). If you can figure out how to make a call (ip to ip) I would accept the answer. I am not super good at python, at least not good enough to understand that code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Consider using python-sipsimple, which seems feature rich and fairly maintained. Instructions on installation and usage are here: https://github.com/AGProjects/python-sipsimple/tree/master/docs

## References

SIP Simple website: https://sipsimpleclient.org
SIP Simple Github: https://github.com/AGProjects/python-sipsimple

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I will accept tomorrow when I get a change to test it out, again, thank you so much, I thought my bounty was wasted :)

Comment: The only issue is python3 support but they seem to be working on that.

Comment: @KetZoomer worst case scenario use or write Python twinkle cli wrapper to call twinkle cli until sipsimple merges Python 3 compatibility

Comment: tried it on bullseye (python 3.9), had to `pip install 'cython<3'` to make it work. Latest cython doesn't have `Cython.DistUtils` module.